# creating nw.js + meteor desktop application

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, desktop-application, node-webkit

I'm trying to create an open source app, which will work on browser and offline as a desktop application on linux, windows and Mac. On the browser app I have no problem. The desktop app is more problematic to me, since I'm no expert. Help me understand if I got this correctly:

Windows, offline desktop application Scenario:

1) User download .exe package. In this scenario it will try to install  node.js, meteor and all relative dependencies

2) nw.js application starts. It asks the user if he either has an online server to point him to, or start itself a meteor server, and load localhost url. in NW.js app.

3) Now everything is the same for offline and online users. Online users will connect to the server, offline user will still connect to the server, except that it runs on localhost.

Am I getting this right?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you can run it this, and it is the "same", except that the online server version will likely be able to do many more things (e.g. connect multiple users). It really depends on what your app does.